# Silent Renewal in Ionic 3 with Identity Server 4

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, oauth, angular5, identityserver4

So I am trying to implement silent renewal in an ionic 3 application, I am still learning about the whole thing so I'll try to be as descriptive as possible please correct me if I am wrong.

**Authentication**

I am using `Implicit` flow for my authentication using the [In App Browser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/).

1. The user is redirected to the authentication server page
2. After a success authentication I retrieve the id-token & access-token

As I understand the `id-token` is for authentication and `access-token` is for authorization with the API.

I have followed [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-an-ionic-app-with-user-authentication) to help me set this up (Particularly the "Deploy to Mobile Device" section) for my Identity Server.

As done in the article I am using [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) to assist me with storing information about redirect links, issuer, etc...

I have attempted to achieve this in 3 different ways, 2 of them work but I don't understand how to retrieve the new `access-token` and `id-token`, and the last one returns an error. each of them left me with questions.

**First: oauthService**

The angular-oauth2-oidc library has a `silentRefresh()` method, and [this github MD](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/blob/master/angular-oauth2-oidc/md/silent-refresh.md) describes how to use it using a hidden iframe very vaguely so I barely understand how this works. I have created a `silent-refresh.html` page in the same directory, but using `http://localhost:8000/silent-refresh.html` return's a `404`. Calling the `silentRefresh()` method successfully re-authenticates on the server side but the request times-out on the client side, as said in the MD file, something is wrong with the iframe.

Question 1: Does the library create a new iframe and then waits for a response to the `http://localhost:8000/silent-refresh.html` page but is never found so I never get my response? How to proceed to retrieve my tokens?

**Second: iframe**

So here I follow [this article](https://damienbod.com/2017/06/02/implementing-a-silent-token-renew-in-angular-for-the-openid-connect-implicit-flow/) where I create an `iframe` and add it to the `body`. I create my own url (similar to the one made by the `silentRefresh()` method), and assign it to the `src` of the `iframe`. Again on the server side everything is fine and it tries to return the tokens to `http://localhost:8000`.

```
public startRenew(url: string) {
        this._sessionIframe.src = url;

        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            this._sessionIframe.onload = () => {
                resolve();
            }
        });
}
```

Question 2: How to proceed to retrieve the tokens? as it doesn't update my tokens automatically, and I don't see how the code above can do it.

**Third: In App Browser**
I thought this would work fine as I already know how to process the request using the `In App Browser`. So I tried to use the same `url` that worked for the `iframe` in the 2nd part. However this returns an error: `prompt=none was requested. But user is not authenticated.` on the server side, which tells that the server can't find the session so it doesn't know who is requesting the token renewal.

Question 3: Is there a specific reason this won't work other than I made a mistake?

NOTE: Took longer than expected to write this will edit this in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**oAuthService**

So I looked in to [the implementation](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/blob/master/angular-oauth2-oidc/src/oauth-service.ts#L693) of the silent refresh, to see what it does. It creates an iframe with a default id, unless you override it. That cleared up a lot of confusion as to what was actually happening.

The next mistake I did was placing the `silent-refresh.html` file in the `src/` folder, that makes it inaccessible to the `iframe`. Instead the file should have been placed in the `www/` folder.

Then inside the `iframe` I kept getting the `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error. This was due to CORS and is solved by editing the `Client` int the `Config.cs` file on the `Authentication Server`:
`AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:8100", "http://<ip>:8100/", "http://<ip>:8100/silent-refresh.html" },`

**WARNING**: This didn't work once I wanted to take this outside serving in the browser (`ionic serve`) or emulating on my device with `ionic cordova run android -c-l-s`, these made the `root url` return something like `http://<ip>/`. But once ran with `ionic cordova run android` (without the flags), `window.location.href` would return `file:///<example>/<something>/index.html`, using this sort of path (`file:///<example>/<something>/silent-refresh.html`) as a redirect url caused an `ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT` error to display in the `iframe`.

Perhaps `silentRefresh()` is an Angular only solution?

**In App Browser**

The mistake that caused the original error was having `clearsessioncache` and `clearcache` set to `yes` when creating the browser, caused the session to be wiped so the authentication server didn't know who it was duh, now reduced to this:

```
const browser = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(oauthUrl, '_blank',
     'location=no, hidden=yes'
);
```

Regular `redirect url` of `http://localhost:8100` could be used to catch the request with the new tokens. And the `silent-refresh.html` page is not needed.

Here is the code for creating the `oauthUrl`:

```
buildOAuthRefreshUrl(nonce): string {
    return this.oauthService.issuer + '/connect/authorize?' +
      'response_type=id_token%20token' +
      '&client_id=' + this.oauthService.clientId +
      '&state=' + nonce +
      '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(this.oauthService.redirectUri) +
      '&scope=' + encodeURI(this.oauthService.scope) +
      '&nonce=' + nonce +
      '&prompt=none';
}
```

The rest of the code is pretty much identical to the [originally mentioned article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-an-ionic-app-with-user-authentication)